# SQL Server Backup (not restore!) error: The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. All members must be provided

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, backup, database-backups

I am running into this error when trying to Backup a database:

> "The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. All
>   members must be provided."

Please note this is on BACKUP not on restore.

There are a lot of topics on this error for RESTORE, but I didn't find any for BACKUP.

I am using this T.SQL on Sql Server 2005:

```
backup database dtplog
TO DISK='e:\dtplog.bak'
```

So it looks like SQL Server has some kind of setting specified there are multiple backup devices for this database.

For some databases I don't get this error, but for some I do.

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: This may be a good question for the DBA stackexchange instead of SO.

Answer (score 0):

This is only for all database backup

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name  
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files  
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup  
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name 

SET @path = 'C:\Backup\'  

SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) 

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')  

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK'  
       BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName  

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```